# How to align text field?

Tags: html, css

I have a login form on the JSP page.

It is almost perfect except that the text field is not align up correctly. I want my text field to look like Facebook's login page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    div.ex
    {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        border:5px solid gray;
        margin:0px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ex">
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<hr>
<form>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID
            <input type="text" name="id"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            password
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">Keep me logged in</label>
        <input type="submit" value="login"/>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is my JSP script and I appreciate someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking the `input` tag out of the `label`.  This will align the label on the left of the input field.  To make the label appear above the input field give it a style of `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can give the form elements id's and then control them with css like any other element.  For example:

```
<style>
    div.ex
    {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        border:5px solid gray;
        margin:0px;
    }
#idBox {
    margin-left: 45px;
}
#lastRow {
    margin-left: 65px;
}
</Style>
<div class="ex">
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<hr>
<form>
    <p>
        <label>
            ID
            <input type="text" name="id" id="idBox"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            password
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <div id="lastRow">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">Keep me logged in</label>
            <input type="submit" value="login"/>
        </div>  
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK3ep/1/)

Comment: Why did you choose 45px and 65px?

Comment: I was lining them up on my screen - i know that's bad, I was just doing it quickly.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TWn9e/

The parent is now relative and the text-boxes absolute with a left of 6em - that makes sure they line up in the same position.

Comment: If I had more than two text fieids (six to be exact), do I just have to align each field dependently?

Comment: No, you could use a common class.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/TWn9e/1/.  They all have the class "align", and that's what's setting the margin.

Comment: Thanks. That works, but the submit button has overlapped with gray box. Can I align the submit button altogether?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the only reason I can think why it might overlap is if the container isn't wide enough.  The login button is part of a div that is aligned to center, so it shouldn't be a problem...  Maybe try making the box wider?

Answer (score 0):

do this in HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="id">
        ID
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="password">
        password

    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
</p>
```

and this in CSS:

```
label{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My css isn't the greatest but i adapted this from the visual quickstart html5 and css book
latest edition. All you do is change text-align to left or right to align the label down the right hand side or the left. If that makes sense. Hope this helps.

```
<form>
<ul id="about_me">
    <li><label>My Height</label>
    <select class="about" name="height">
     option value="">Choose from list</option>
    </select>
     </li>
</ul>
</form>


ul#about_me label
{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:3px 6px;
 text-align:left;
 width:170px;
 vertical-align:top;
 }
```